# LaTeX TikZ: Creating a sophisticated flow chart - How to create diagonal decision boxes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I'm a LaTeX beginner and I'm struggling with creating a flow chart. I have the following code so far:

```
\documentclass[final, english]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,trees,graphs,positioning, arrows, chains, shapes, arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]

    \tikzstyle{process1} = [rectangle, minimum width=11cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black] 
    \tikzstyle{process2} = [rectangle, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black] 
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, base, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, aspect=2, inner xsep=0mm]
    \tikzstyle{stop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
    
    %Nodes erstellen
    \node (start) [process1] {\begin{tabular}{c}
        Box 1: Row 1 \\
        Row 2
    \end{tabular}};    
    
    %Process boxes
    \node (p2) [process1, below of=start, yshift = -0.2cm] {Box 2};
    \node (p3) [process1, below of=p2] {Box 3};
    \node (p4) [process1, below of=p3] {Box 4};
    \node (p5) [process1, below of=p4] {Box 5};

    %decision boxes
    \node (dec1) [decision, below left of=p5, yshift=-1.5cm] {\begin{tabular}{c}
        Decision Box 1: Row 1 \\
        Row 2 \\
        Row 3 \\
        Row 4
    \end{tabular}};     
    \node (dec2) [decision, below right of=dec1, yshift=-4cm] {\begin{tabular}{c}
        Decision Box 2: Row 1 \\
        Row 2 \\
        Row 3 \\
        Row 4
    \end{tabular}};       
    
    %small process boxes
    \node (p6) [process2, below left of=dec1, yshift=-2cm] {\begin{tabular}{c}
        Box 6: Row 1 \\
        Row 2 \\
        Row 3 
    \end{tabular}};   
    
    \node (p7) [process2, below of=dec2, yshift=-2cm] {\begin{tabular}{c}
        Box 7: Row 1 \\
        Row 2 \\
        Row 3 
    \end{tabular}};    
    
    \node (p7) [process2, below of=dec2] {\begin{tabular}{c}
        Box 7: row 1\\
        row 2
    \end{tabular}};
    
    \node (dec3) [decision, below of=p6, yshift=-2cm] {Decision box};
    
    \node (p8) [process2, below of=p7] {\begin{tabular}{c}
        Box 7: row 1\\
        row 2
    \end{tabular}};

    \node (dec4) [decision, below right of=dec3, yshift=-2cm] {\begin{tabular}{c}
        Last decision box \\
        another row
    \end{tabular}};    
    
    \node (stop) [stop, right of=dec4] {STOP};
    
    % arrows
    \draw [arrow] (start) -- (p2);
    \draw [arrow] (p2) -- (p3);
    \draw [arrow] (p3) -- (p4);
    \draw [arrow] (p4) -- (p5);    
    
    % Labeled arrows
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node {Yes} (p6);
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node {No} (dec2);
    
    \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node {Yes} (p7);
    \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node {No} (p8);
    
    \draw [arrow] (dec3) -- node {Yes} (dec1);
    \draw [arrow] (dec3) -- node {No} (dec4);
    
    \draw [arrow] (dec4) -- node {Yes} (stop);
    \draw [arrow] (dec4) -- node {No} (p4);
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am currently failing because the decision boxes are diagonally next to each other. In the end, the flow chart should look as similar as possible to the template and accordingly I also have to manage the alignment so that it is formatted in the same way.

1. How do I get decision boxes 1 and 2 aligned diagonally next to each other?
2. What trick is there so that the arrows make angular curves at certain points and do not end directly in a box, but in other arrows?
3. is there a better way to create a line break within the boxes than to make a tabular environment?

I would like to thank everyone who can help me!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: 1. Those boxes are not strictly aligned one to another. You can do it by try and error. 2. Something like `\draw[->] (node1) |-([yshift=5pt] node2.north)` would work. 3. Add `text width` into your node declaration, which allocates a specific width to the text and force line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

Just to let you see the idea of what I said in my comment. This is not the best way to do that, but at least, it's customizable and easy to understand. The first boxes could (should?) be done using `chain`, which requires less code. Anyway:

[image: flowchart]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes}

\tikzset{
    process1/.style={rectangle, minimum width=11cm, minimum height=1cm, text width=10cm,text centered, draw=black},
    process2/.style={rectangle, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=1cm, text width=5cm,text centered, draw=black},
    decision/.style={diamond, text centered, draw=black, aspect=2, inner xsep=-2mm},
    stop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
    arr/.style={thick,-stealth}
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
        \node[process1] (start) {Initiate the seed permutation sequence by a proven scheduling heuristic: Set of scheduled jobs $=\lbrace\delta\rbrace$};
        \node[below = of start,process1] (box2) {Pick the first job that occurs in $\lbrace\delta\rbrace$};
        \node[below = of box2,process1] (box3) {Whatever text you want to put here};
        \node[below = of box3,process1] (box4) {Whatever text you want to put here};
        \node[below = of box4,process1] (box5) {Whatever text you want to put here};
        
        \node[below left =2cm and -3cm of box5,decision,text width=4cm] (dec1) {On the following machine stage, can job be inserted completely ahead of preceding job in $\lbrace\delta\rbrace$};
        \node[below right = 1cm and 2cm of dec1,decision,text width=4cm] (dec2) {Is insertion including job shifting of precding jobs in $\lbrace\delta\rbrace$ possible?};
        
        \node[below left = 2cm and -3cm of dec1,process2] (p6) {Implement insertion of job, compute its ST and FT on machine \textit{i}, reschedule jobs in $\lbrace\delta\rbrace$ which are affected by insertion on machine \textit{i}};
        
        \node[below = 4cm of  p6,decision] (p7) {$i< m$?};
        
        \draw[arr] (start) -- (box2);
        \draw[arr] (box2) -- (box3);
        \draw[arr] (box3) -- (box4);
        \draw[arr] (box4) -- (box5);
        \draw[arr] (box5.south) --++ (0,-10pt) -| (dec1);
        \draw[arr] (dec1) -| (dec2) node[pos=0.1,above]{\textit{No}};
        \draw[arr] (dec1.south) --++ (0,-10pt) -| (p6) node[pos=0.3,above]{\textit{Yes}};
        \draw[arr] (p6) -- (p7);
        \draw[arr] (dec2) |- ([yshift=20pt]p7.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit different design, in flowchart code is employed the `chains` library:

```
\documentclass[final, english]{scrreprt}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains, 
                positioning, 
                quotes,
                shapes.symbols}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{FlowChart/.style={
suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}},
    off chain/.code={\def\tikz@lib@on@chain{}},
%
node distance = 7mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going below,
%
   arr/.style = {thick,-Stealth},
  base/.style = {draw, semithick, minimum height=3ex, align=center}, 
proces/.style = {base, text width=##1},
proces/.default = 24em,
decision/.style = {signal, signal pointer angle=120,
                   signal to=west and east, 
                   base, text width=##1, inner xsep=0ex},
decision/.default = 8em,
  stop/.style = {rounded corners, fill=gray!10, minimum width=12ex},
                            }
        }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart]
%   Nodes erstellen
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain, join=by arr}]
\node (s)   [proces]    {Initiate the seed permutation sequence by a proven scheduling heuristic: Set of scheduled jobs $=\{\delta\}$};
%   Process boxes
\node (p2) [proces]     {Box 2};
\node (p3) [proces]     {Box 3};
\node (p4) [proces]     {Box 4};
\coordinate (aux0);
\node (p5) [proces]     {Box 5};
\coordinate (aux1);
%   decision boxes
\node (d1) [decision=12em]   
                        {On the following machine stage, can job be inserted completely ahead of preceding job in $\{\delta\}$};
%   left branch
\node (p6)  [proces=9em, 
off chain, suppress join,
             below left=of d1]   {Implement insertion of job, compute its ST and FT on machine $i$, reschedule jobs in $\{\delta\}$ which are affected by insertion on machine $i$};
\coordinate [below=of p6]   (aux2);
\node (d2)  [decision, 
             below=14mm of aux2]   {$i\leq m$ ?};
\node (d3)  [decision]   {Are al jobs in $\{\delta\}$ considered};
    \end{scope}
%   right branch
\node (d4)  [decision=9em, 
             below right=of d1] {Is insertion including job shifting of precding jobs in $\{\delta\}$ possible?};
\node (p7)  [proces=12em,
             below left=of d4]       {Implement insertion of job, compute its ST and FT on machine $i$, reschedule jobs in $\{\delta\}$ an machine $i$ to $m$ and check further possible job swaps};
\node (p8)  [proces=8em,
             below=of d4]  {Compute ST and FT of this job on machine $i$};
% end flowchart
\node (s)   [stop,
             right=of d3 -| p7] {STOP};
%   connection not included in join macro
    \draw[arr] (d1.west) node[above left]   {Yes} -|  (p6); 
    \draw[arr] (d1.east) node[above right]  {No} -|  (d4);
    
    \draw[arr] (d2.west) node[above left]   {Yes} -|  ([xshift=-2.2em] p6.west) |- (aux1);
    \draw[arr] (d3.west) node[above left]   {No}  -|  ([xshift=-3em] p6.west) |- (aux0);

    \draw[arr] (d4.west) node[above left]   {Yes} -| (p7);
    \draw[arr] (d4.south) -- node[right]    {No}  (p8)
               (p7.west |- aux2) -- (aux2); 
    \draw[arr] (p8) |- (d2);
    \draw[arr] (d3.east) node[above right]  {Yes}  -- (s);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)